# lambda function for inplace methods/functions

Tags: python, lambda

For a function that operates on objects in place like `x.sort()` or `np.random.shuffle(x)`, to use it in lambda function, we need to find the corresponding function that returns a copy like `sorted(x)` or `np.random.permutation(x)`.

If there is no such corresponding function, is there a way to use it with lambda function? E.g.:

```
def f(x):
    x.sort()     #or x.copy().sort()
    return(x)
```

Comment: Can you show the lambda that is the problem?

Comment: I just want to convert the above `f` into `lambda`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fundamental problem isn't that `.sort` works in-place, it's that it *returns `None`*. You can get around that using the return value of an `or` expression:

```
>>> x = [3,1,2]
>>> (lambda a: a.sort() or a)(x)
[1, 2, 3]
```

So, you *can* do this, but you *should **not** do this*:
Just use a normal function. The **only** advantage of a `lambda` function is that it is anonymous. That is a very minor advantage, one of mostly convenience.

And, just for fun:

```
>>> import random
>>> (lambda a: random.shuffle(a) or a)(x)
[2, 3, 1]
>>> (lambda a: random.shuffle(a) or a)(x)
[2, 1, 3]
>>> (lambda a: random.shuffle(a) or a)(x)
[3, 1, 2]
```

But I reiterate: **don't do this**.

Comment: I suggest `sorted(a)`.

Comment: @JeremyMcGibbon yes, of course. I would **never** use the above `lambda`, I hope I was clear on that point.

Comment: Yep! I just wanted to point out a particular "normal function" that does what this user is trying to do, in case they don't know one.

Comment: Is something like `lambda x: 1 if x.sort() else x` safer?

Comment: @user322 Define "safer". Logically, that is no different than using `or x`